# How do I physically identify a drive for someone in the office to remove? (remote work)

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I'm working from home, and there's a drive failing on a server. There are two identical drives side by side, and I'm not sure which is which, all I know is that /dev/sdc is failing and /dev/sdd is fine. I want someone in the office to remove /dev/sdc from the machine, but I don't know how to identify to them (or even myself) which one of the two disks to remove.

They're internal drives, so they don't have any lights or anything on them. My only thought at the moment is to run a big transfer on the drive I want to keep, and unmount the other. The office admin can feel for the disk that is rotating/working and unplug the other disk, however that's not necessarily foolproof. Another question/answer says to use hdparm, but that involves the user on the other end picking up the drive and/or getting on the floor to read the serial number, which may be hard to find with bad eyes.

How do I physically identify which drive is sdc vs which is sdd?

Comment: You need the manufacturer's drive app to identify the state of drives by drive ID.  That is how we do it.  If there is no drive app software, you will have to attend to the drive.

Comment: I've always done it by shutting down, pulling one drive at random, then powering up & seeing if I got the right one ;-)) It's not exactly the smartest method, but it works. [That, plus you cannot see any of the drive's label or other data with it in situ. Case just doesn't allow it.] I usually write identifiers on the drive sled for the important machines.

Comment: Could see if you could grab the serial number of the drive through the CLI and then convey that information to your colleague. They could shut the server down then check the serials on the disks.

Comment: @SamForbis I'd really like to avoid shutting a server down for something like this. Not only because I'm in an uptime competition with other server admins, but because I'm actively using the server and because the admin who will be pulling the drive is busy, so I'd rather give a "pull x drive at some point in the next few days" than a "right now" order

Comment: @BrydonGibson - You will have to shutdown the server to unplug the drive regardless.  Getting the serial through the CLI sounds like the best approach.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you sure? Sata is hot-pluggable, this wouldn't be the first drive that I've hot plugged on this server

Comment: @BrydonGibson - There are all kinds of servers in the world.  SATA being hot swappable depends on the hardware being used in most cases.

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting, I always learn a lot of things when I ask questions here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the drive is still working, you can use `smartctl -i /dev/sdc` to get its serial number.

If the drives are not properly labeled with their serial numbers, that’s far as you can go. Ask your IT dept to label all drives at their earliest convenience.

If this is a server system with a proper backplane, you may be able to use the (RAID) controller management tool to blink the drive’s LED. Check for `/sys/block/sdc/device/enclosure_device*`. I don’t have any devices with enclosures so I cannot verify this.

If each drive has its own activity LED, you could create lots of activity on the device, for example using `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null`. If drives do not have their own activity LED, the person looking for the drive could go by sound or touch (vibrations). Not exactly 100% reliable, of course. Keeping the drive busy for extended periods of time is also not advisable, especially if it’s about to fail.